# Execution reverted: ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, ethers.js

I am using hardhat for testing my contracts and frontend. My application works without any error with Metamask on local node environment with hardhat. For that I just start `npx hardhat node` and then I deploy the contract with `npx hardhat run deploy.js --network localhost`

Now, I want to test it on rinkeby and set my hardhat-config.js like this:

```
networks: {
    localhost: {
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8545',
      chainId: 31337,
    },
    hardhat: {},
    rinkeby: {
      url: 'https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/${key}',
      accounts: [
        `0x${key}`,
      ],
    },
  },
```

and deploy my contract again to rinkeby instead of localhost like this:

```
npx hardhat run deploy.js --network rinkeby
```

But now I am getting following error:

> inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: execution reverted: ERC20: transfer
> amount exceeds allowance {code: -32603, message: "execution reverted:
> ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance",

The code which approves on frontend is:

```
  approveAddLiquidity = async (
    dexAddress: string,
    tokenAmount: string,
    ethAmount: string
  ) => {
    const exchange = await this.getExchange(dexAddress);

    await this.state.token.approve(dexAddress, tokenAmount, {
      from: this.state.account,
    }); // <-- seems to be not working on rinkeby and metamask???

    const tx = await exchange.addLiquidity(tokenAmount, {
      value: ethAmount,
      from: this.state.account,
    });
    await tx.wait(1);
    return tx;
  };
```

I tried with different account and also with görli network but same issue. I could not reproduce it. Don't understand why it is working on my localhost but not on rinkeby. What I am doing wrong? Any idea?

Comment: For interacting with functions in smart contract which uses tokens as their payments to do something, like adding liquidity, you can't transfer token to them directly! You allow them to receive token from you. If I want to say it in solidity language `transfer(recever, amount)` is not used and `transferFrom(sender, recever, amount)` function is used! So first you have to use tokens approve function like this `Approve(CONTRACT_YOU_WANT_TO_ADD_LIQUIDITY, amount)` by the wallet you want to use to add liquidity with. And error you receive says you did not approve enough token to use tranferFrom!

Answer (score 1):

This is a mining issue. A live chain and localhost differ in terms of how they mine. Your localhost might be set to automine, for example, which Rinkeby does not do. So in one case the `approve` transaction completes, and so `addLiquidity` works, whereas on Rinkeby it fails, because you are not waiting for the `approve` tx to complete. Try an `await tx.wait()` between transactions.